# PLSQL extract procudures oracle 9i

Tags: plsql, oracle9i

I have an anonymous block that extract all Procedures for a database and then it writes each procedure in a file.

It work fine when I use **utl_file.put_line** (except that for each line is and space between each line) 
If I use **utl_file.put** the procedures are incomplete no exceptions

```
/*
create or replace directory plsql_path as '/u020/apps/klainet/plsql';
grant ALL on directory plsql_path to public;
select * from dba_directories;*/


DECLARE 
tmp_name VARCHAR2(255) :='PROCEDURE';
v_path VARCHAR2(100) := '/u020/apps/klainet/plsql';
v_File_name VARCHAR2(100);
v_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
v_flag BOOLEAN := FALSE;
str_len NUMBER; 
loop_count NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  FOR line IN ( SELECT * FROM all_source WHERE OWNER NOT IN('SYS','SYSTEM') ORDER BY OWNER, TYPE,NAME, LINE) LOOP
    IF tmp_name <> line.NAME THEN

      IF v_flag = TRUE THEN
        BEGIN
          UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error al escribir la linea '|| line.owner ||' ' || line.name);
        END;

      END IF;

      tmp_name := line.NAME;
      v_File_name := line.owner||'.'||line.NAME||'.sql';
      --dbms_output.put_line(v_file_name);
      BEGIN
        v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('PLSQL_PATH', v_File_name, 'w');
        v_File_name:='';
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No se pudo crear el archivo de salida ' || v_File_name);
      END;
      v_flag := TRUE;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
      --UTL_FILE.PUT(v_file, line.text);
      str_len := LENGTH(line.text);
      loop_count := 0;
      WHILE loop_count < str_len
      LOOP 
        SYS.utl_file.put_line(v_file, substr( line.text, loop_count +1, 255 ));
        loop_count := loop_count +255; 
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        loop_count :=0;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error al escribir la linea '|| line.owner ||' ' || line.name);
    END;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

I don't fine any diference between put and put_line, except the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE` will flush output to the physical file. `UTL_FILE.PUT` won't.
If you want to use `PUT` you need to flush the file manually; thus, replace `fFile.PUT_LINE('whatever');` with `fFile.PUT('whatever'); fFile.FFLUSH;`.

Best of luck.

Comment: Correct answer it was very helpful i just have to add fFile.FFLUSH(file)